Why does water reflection in the rendered viewport, look like smoke in the final output blender in cycles.?

its supposed to look like what's on the top image and what it looks like is on the bottom image which is the final output, how can I solve that

When you ask questions and post screenshots, it would be better not to crop and not to resize them so that the full UI with settings is visible. Nobody likes to look at low resolution screenshots where you cannot see anything. There are often important details in them that might help people identify problems.

Looks like denoising with not enough samples. Increase the amount of samples an/or try using Normal input for denoising.
If you are using a video format with compression this might also be caused by the compression. You could try rendering to exr image sequence and compress that to a video format as a separate step to have more control about how much quality you loose with compression without the need to re-render.
